# 'Undefined function' in fresh WordPress install?

Tags: wordpress

I've been having a problem with my media browser for weeks and haven't been able to solve it. When browsing to insert an image, the media library shows absolutely nothing, just blank white. I see tabs telling me that it sees the objects in the library, but they do not display as thumbnails to select.

For some reason it just occurred to me (a-doy) to look at my server logs - turns out my ISP has been suppressing PHP errors. The error I'm getting is this:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function get_post_thumbnail_id() in
>   REDACTED/wp-admin/includes/media.php
>   on line 1292, referer:
>   http://REDACTED/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=877&type=image&amp;

Now this is baffling - I did a completely fresh install of WordPress to try and solve this problem, and yet I'm still getting an "undefined function" error. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you have to initialize theme support before get_post_thumbnail_id() can be used.

```
<?php add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails

Comment: I owe you a high-five and a steak.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')` function is run before `init`. I know this has screwed me up when I had it in a hook tied into `init`.

If it has to be hooked in, it should be hooked into `after_setup_theme`